# The share link box is oversized

Tags: bug, design, meta, css

I've been able to reproduce this in both Firefox and Chromium.

[image]

I click the `share` button then this box appears with a abnormal horizontal compared with the main site

[image]

Apparently, the comment field/button also goes down:

[image]

I was able to figure out where the problem is but not how to fix it. The div `share-icons` has some issue, but the thing is... that it has the same css rules as main site.

Comment: Confirmed on Google Chrome too, this seems to be a bug in Meta only that is browser-independent.

Comment: I'm seen this for a long time.. So +1

Comment: Works fine on IE10 and Chrome on Windows8.

Comment: Seems to not be a problem on my 13.04 + firefox 24.

Comment: @YetAnotherUser you sure, I'm using the very same version.

Comment: @Braiam no, the share box DEFINITELY doesn't occupy that much space. Might be screen resolution? I'm at 1366x768 on an old laptop.